# How much time from H1B approval to US entry?

Tags: usa, immigration, h1-visa

Once H1B has been approved, an interview at a US embassy is required.
Which steps are involved from the moment an employer notifies about the approval of H1B and the entrance in the US? (for example, scheduling the interview, possible medical examinations, approval after interview, if & how long they keep passports etc).
How long does it take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking through the experience of going through this process and also meeting people who went through this process from other regions of the world. It varies, in my case, I applied for it in western Europe:

From the time of the H1B approval to the time I got the interview, it took me 2 weeks, and from the interview to get my passport back with the visa stamp it took about 3 days.

Other friends have complained to me about long waiting periods 1~2 months eastern Asia.

Comment: Great! Did you hear from anyone in Canada by any chance? I have the option choosing Canada (where I am now) or Germany (home country).

Comment: I would opt for germany based on personal experience. Very fast and kind. BTW, I understood that due to COVID H1-B Visas are now blocked

Comment: Do you have a pointer for that? I think they were temporarily blocked but to my knowledge they are active again (and my application is in progress -- hopefully). Also, premium processing was stopped temporarily (in June I think) but to my knowledge has been resumed. I can't find definite information though, so if you have some would be appreciated.

Comment: I do no have recent knowledge on that, similarly to you I read it in major newspaper back in Spring that Trump administration blocked H1B visas and new green card applications from current h1b visa holders (such as I).

Comment: @divB you can find my info in m y stack exchange profile, I can share with you more personal details of my case.